# how to add custom function in magento onepage?

Tags: php, magento

i am struggling with magento add custom function for checkout  method.

how to get popup messages after click the "onepage-guest-register-button" in checkout method.Also need to send email to the vendor with the selected product id in magento.

I am new in magento,any one please help to me.

Thanks,

Comment: Explain us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize login template here:

```
[Magento root]/app/design/frontend/[your theme package]/[your theme]/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/login.phtml
```

or here

```
[Magento root]/app/design/frontend/[your theme package]/[your theme]/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml
```

If you want send mail when someone add product to cart (or something else) you have to check about observer (events handler) on Magento.